# "Since" vs "that"

Tags: adverbs

1. "Tomorrow will be 3 weeks **that** I have been working on this project" (means a continuous process that hasn't ended yet)
2. Tomorrow will be 3 weeks **since** I have started working on this project (means a continuous process that hasn't ended yet)

Is there a difference between "that" and "since" in these examples? Are they interchangeable?

Comment: The second is ungrammatical.  'Tomorrow will be 3 weeks since I started working on this project' describes a continuous process that started three weeks ago and may or may not still be continuing.

Comment: And that's the difference between _since_ and _that_. _Since_ has a specific temporal reference (a length of time stretching from a point in past time up to the present), while _that_ has no reference at all -- it merely introduces a tensed clause.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The second is not ungrammatical. It just has a different meaning than the first. It's theoretically possible for something to have been worked on continuously for 3 weeks. Let's say somebody is testing a new model of insulin pump—they can be working on the project, having data sent to a computer, even while they are asleep. The objection is one of common semantics, not of syntax.